# Is Duplicate Management detecting duplicate records inside a bulk dml transaction?

Tags: duplicate-management, bulk

I'm getting a really weird behavior from the new Duplicate Catcher in Salesforce. It seems like sometimes, the standard Duplicate Catcher will catch duplicate when doing a bulk operation, but some other times, **it won't**.

Here's an example where it works (same email, blocking operation if dupe):

```
Account account1 = new Account(
  Name = 'Sample Company',
  Email__c = 'test@example.com',
  BillingCountry = 'JP'
);

Account account2 = new Account(
  Name = 'Some Different Company',
  Email__c = 'test@example.com',
  BillingCountry = 'JP'
);

insert new Account[]{account1,account2};
```

Here's an example where it doesn't work (same name - using fuzzy, blocking operation if dupe):

```
Account account1 = new Account(
    Name = 'Sample Company',
    Email__c = 'test@example.com',
    BillingCountry = 'JP'
);

Account account2 = new Account(
    Name = 'Sample Company',
    Email__c = 'test2@example.com',
    BillingCountry = 'JP'
);

insert new Account[]{account1,account2};
```

The first scenario seems to work at all time. If I bulkify, add one single record or anything else, it will return an error and prevent from saving - on the UI, Anonymous Apex or through the API.

However, the second scenario doesn't work on bulkify - it will allow users to create dupe records where the name is the same. If I try to do it in two seperate DML requests, the Duplicate Management tool will notify me and prevent from saving, whatever way I used to create that record.

---

Here's the configuration:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

I looked at the documentation and I didn't see any limitation related to that. Have you experienced something alike?

---

## EDIT

It seems like the field was set to unique. Considering this, my conclusion is that duplicate management rules are ignoring duplicate records inside the same transaction.

Answer (score 1):

@jpmonette You are right.
From the doc ["**Things to Know About Duplicate Rules**"](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=duplicate_rules_overview.htm&type=5)

> **Timing of Saves**
>   If *multiple records are saved simultaneously* and your
>   duplicate rule is set to block or alert sales reps, *those records
>   aren’t compared with each other. They’re compared only with records
>   already in Salesforce.* This behavior doesn't affect the Report option,
>   and duplicate record sets do include records that match other records
>   saved simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is going to help but you could use some Apex before insert to check for it yourself. I use this function to get the duplicates:

```
public static List<SObject> checkForDuplicates(List<Contact> contacts){
    List<sObject> duplicateRecords = new List<sObject>();
    Datacloud.FindDuplicatesResult[] results = Datacloud.FindDuplicates.findDuplicates(contacts);
    for(Datacloud.FindDuplicatesResult findDupeResult : results){
        for(Datacloud.DuplicateResult dupeResult : findDupeResult.getDuplicateResults()){
            for(Datacloud.MatchResult matchResult : dupeResult.getMatchResults()){
                for(Datacloud.MatchRecord matchRecord : matchResult.getMatchRecords()){
                    duplicateRecords.add(matchRecord.getRecord());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return duplicateRecords;
}
```